# What's more performing between an EXCEL formula, a PIVOT TABLE and VBA code?

Tags: performance, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I have a (growing) table of data with 40.000 rows and 20 columns.

I need to group these data (by month and week) and to perform some simple operations (+ & /) between rows/columns.

I must be able to change the period in question and some specific rows to sum up. I know how to macro/pivot/formula, but I didn't started yet, and I would like the recalculation process to be the fastest possible, not that I click a button and then everything freezes for minutes.

Do you have any idea on what could be the most efficient solution?

Thank you

Comment: You could try to test how long it takes to refresh the formula based solution against how long it takes to update the pivotcache.  Test with different row depths to see if there's any divergence in times as the data grows?

Answer (score 2):

Excel have it's limits to store and analyze data at the same time.

If you're planning to build a growing database at MS Excel, at some point you will add so much data that the Excel files will not work. (or using them won't be time effective)

Before you get to that point you should be looking for alternate storage options as a scalable data solution.

They can be simple, like an Access DB, sqlite, PostgreSQL, Maria DB, or even PowerPivot (though this can have it's own issues).

Or  more complex, like storing the data into a database, then adding an analysis cube and pulling smaller slices of data from these databases, into Excel for analysis and reporting.

Regardless of what you end up doing you will have to change how Excel interacts with the data.

You need to move all of the raw data to another system (Access or SQL are the easiest, but Excel supports a lot of other DB options) and pull smaller chunks of data back into Excel for time effective analysis.

---

Useful Links:

- [SQL Databases vs Excel](http://schoolofdata.org/2013/11/07/sql-databases-vs-excel/)
- [Using Access or Excel to manage your data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-Access-or-Excel-to-manage-your-data-09576147-47d1-4c6f-9312-e825227fcaea)